# Al generar el .jar No abre las interfaces que deberia

Tags: java, jar

mi problema es que tengo un proyecto terminado en NetBeans que funciona correctamente en el IDE, sin embargo, al generar el jar y utilizarlo este ya no me abre dos interfaces del programa, no me marca errores ni nada, pero las demás interfaces si siguen funcionando correctamente. Alguna sugerencia de cual podría ser el error?

Comment: ¿Es aplicación de escritorio?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Al ejecutar desde netbeans funciona perfectamente, lo mismo cuando ejecuto el jar desde la pc en la cuál fue creado el programa. El problema está cuando quiero ejecutarlo en otra pc diferente (es igual a la que utilice cuando creé el programa, windows 10, arquitectura de 64bits, etc).
Se ejecuta (en la pc donde NO fue creado), abre la JFrame principal, y al tocar un botón (debería abrir otra JFrame), no lo hace, y en admin. de tareas queda como ejecutándose.

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo Eclipse, y cuando exporto un programa de escritorio como .jar tengo que indicar en el export cual es la clase main (la que se abrirá primero)

Si después tienes todas las demás enlazadas podrás verlas accediendo a los menús.